# Full width horizontal menu with vertical sub-menu which has a vertical child sub-menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I need some codes or opensource where I need a menu of this kind:

menu 1: 
[image]

menu 2: 
[image]

Image of Menu 1 is the sub menu from the main navigation and

Image of Menu 2 is vertical and if the sub menu is longer than just one column (defined height as on the image), it goes to the second column and further child sub-menu of sub-menu move to the right replacing the "Comment..." as shown in the images.

the defined width is 960px. (non-responsive)

And this is the Fiddle with minimal code: http://jsfiddle.net/jVfB9/

HTML:

```
<div id="pageMenu">

    <div id="pageMenuWrapper">
        <a href="index.html" class="pageMenuLink pageMenuLinkSelected">Menu1</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="pageMenuLink">Menu2</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="pageMenuLink">Menu3</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pageMenu{
    position:relative;
    width:960px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    }
#pageMenuWrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:88px;
    }
.pageMenuLink{
    float:left;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova';
    font-size:16px;
    display:block;
    padding:2px 6px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    }
.pageMenuLink:hover{
    background-color:#D8DBE1;
    }
.pageMenuLinkSelected{
    background-color:#d8dbe1;
    }
```

Comment: This question could be an off-topic: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: well i forgot to add this:
here's my code:
http://goo.gl/Rgamzk
It is only the top menu... how can I expand that?

Comment: *Well*, it didn't make it better. Please post some relevant code here or make a Demo on online tools like jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: And this is the Fiddle with minimal code: http://jsfiddle.net/jVfB9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have solved it:

this is the final [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/RPETZ/1/)

all I had to do was to add border properties to these two clases:

```
.menu-main li.hover a {
    transition-property: background-color, color;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom:6px solid #004062;
    }

.submenu li a {
    font:18px/22px 'focobold';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #383838;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left:4px;
    height: auto !important;
    border-bottom:none !important;
    }
```

Hence a 100% working solution to my question. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to my own question, it took a while, but i got it resolved:

this is my [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/RPETZ/)

but I'm stuck at this point where I've to keep the parent menu element active while I hover the sub menu elements.

I did try the following CSS format

```
.parent-menu > li > a{
hover style;
}
```

but that didn't help.

Can anyone suggest me a possible solution?

Thanks :)